# jQuery - iterating over all the classes in the DOM, assigning a condition by intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok so I'm trying to use jQuery (or Javascript as a whole, doesn't matter to me. But no other Javascript frameworks) to iterate over a given class in a document.

I'm wondering, is there a jQuery specific way of doing it, or should I use Javascript?

Basically there are X instances of a class. I want to iterate over all instances of the class in the DOM, and with each increment, assign a different color to that element (probably by inserting a style tag into the div, that way the original CSS will not be an issue), up to a total of five colors, at which point the next iteration will be given the first color, and the procession continues, etc.

Pseudocode:

```
for x in elements
elements[0].inserttag('style = "#color0"')
elements[1].inserttag('style = "#color1"')
elements[2].inserttag('style = "#color2"')
elements[3].inserttag('style = "#color3"')
elements[4].inserttag('style = "#color4"')
elements[5].inserttag('style = "#color5"')
Repeat for elements[6] and beyond, starting with color0
```

Comment: And of course, it is entirely not working. It doesn't seem to even be inserting in the CSS of the page.

Comment: If you intend for there to be a time element to the solution (e.g. styles applied over some time interval), then you need to clarify that part of your question as the answers provided so far are attempting to guess what you meant.  Your question is not very clear in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

```
var colors = ['color0', 'color1', 'color2', 'color3', 'color4', 'color5'];

$('.your_class').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('color', colors[i  % colors.length]);
});
```

To handle interval:

```
var i = 0,
    colors = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'black'];

function setColor() {
    $('.your_class').eq(i).css('color', colors[i % colors.length]);
    i++;
    setTimeout(function() {
        setColor();
    }, 2000)
}

setColor();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/191/)**

Comment: Couple of things. You didn't handle the interval things. And you could not use `each` when using `css`

Comment: Your interval only runs over the first 6 objects and then stops.

Answer (score 1):

If the class name you want to iterate objects for is "foo", then you could use this jQuery:

```
var colors = ['color0', 'color1', 'color2', 'color3', 'color4', 'color5'];
$(".foo").each(function(index, el) {
    el.style.color = colors[index % colors.length];
});
```

In plain javascript, this is pretty easy too:

```
var colors = ['color0', 'color1', 'color2', 'color3', 'color4', 'color5'];
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    items[i].style.color = colors[i % colors.length];
}
```

If you're trying to apply these color values periodically over some time interval (your question is not clear on this part), then you can do that like this:

```
var colors = ['color0', 'color1', 'color2', 'color3', 'color4', 'color5'];
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
var i = 0;
function nextColor() {
    if (i < items.length) {
        items[i].style.color = colors[i % colors.length];
        i++;
        setTimeout(nextColor, 2000);
    }
}
nextColor();
```

Comment: Do you have any idea, what he wants? Did I miss something in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10984580/601179)?

Comment: @gdoron - One reference to `interval` in the title of the question is entirely not clear what it means.  I provided a simple means of setting alternating styles on a series of objects with the same class.  If the OP wants more than that, they should clarify their question and I've added a comment to the original question to that regard.

Answer (score 1):

You can try caching your colors in an array, and then using `.each()` to iterate through each element:

```
var colors = ['red','white','blue','green','yellow'];
$('.someclass').each(function(i,v) {

    // i is the iteration count,

    $(this).css('color', colors[i % colors.length]);

});
```

... or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'black'];
var index = 0;
function doIt(){
    $('.foo').css('color', colors[index++ % colors.length]);

}

setInterval(doIt, 500);​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yYqm/1)

Comment: This is not what I want AT ALL.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander. And what is that you want?